# How to replace all .success() and .error() calls with .then()?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an older AngularJS project that has a lot of code and instead of `then()` in code `success()` and `error()` is used.

Is there any painless way or recommendation how to turn all `success()` and `error()` into `then()` without having to change everything manually?

Comment: The non-standard `.success` and `.error` methods were a bad bit of API design in the first place. It is best to remove them and use the standard `.then` and `.catch` methods. See [Why are AngularJS $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35331339/5535245).